# Capturing logentry history in post_save signal django

Tags: python, django, logging

I have written a `post_save` signal that is like this :

```
def send_something(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = LogEntry.objects.get(
            content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance).pk,
             object_id      =  instance.pk,
             action_flag    =   1
             ).user

post_save.connect(send_something, sender=ClassName)
```

But I get a `DoesNotExist LogEntry matching query does not exist` when I try to add a `ClassName` object from the admin.

Why does it happen ? Why is the history not available at the time of `post_save` ? Isn't my object saved yet ?

Answer (score 1):

`self.pk` seems to be your problem, try replacing it with `instance.pk`

Comment: Nope that was just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Is this LogEntry being saved somewhere else?
Because you're trying to retrieve a log entry after a post save, but those logentries are only created automatically when using the Admin. If you're not using it, chances are that these logs are not being saved. You could use this post_save signal to create those entries first.